# Compact set contained in an open set.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Today I was solving some exercises about topology but one of them it's so strange. First of all the exercise:

> Let $A\times B$ be a compact set of $X\times Y$ (with the product topology) and $U\subseteq X\times Y$ an open set such that $A\times B\subseteq U$. Prove that there exist $V$ an open set of $X$ and $W$ an open set of $Y$ such that $A\times B\subseteq V\times W\subseteq U$.

My proof:

Take $(x,y)\in A\times B$. Then $(x,y)\in U$ and by hyphotesis $U$ is an open set. Then there exist $V^{x}$ an open set of $X$ and $W^{y}$ an open set of $Y$ such that $(x,y)\in V^{x}\times W^{y}\subseteq U$. Define $V=\bigcup\{V^{x}\mid x\in A \}$ and $W=\bigcup\{W^{y}\mid y\in B \}$. Clearly $V$ and $W$ are open sets of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. We claim that $V\times W$ is the desired open set. For this, consider $(x,y)\in A\times B$. Then by definition $(x,y)\in V\times W$. Finally, we need to see that $$V\times W=\left(\bigcup\{V^{x}\mid x\in A \}\right)\times \left(\bigcup\{W^{y}\mid y\in B \}\right)=\bigcup\{V^{x}\times W^{y}\mid (x,y)\in A\times B \}\subseteq U$$. Therefore, the proof is complete.

Here the problem is that I didn't use the compactness of $A\times B$. Am I missing something? Where is my mistake? Any hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This proof fails because $V^{x}$ and $W^{y}$ actually depend on both $x$ and $y$.

If you call these $V ^{x,y}$ and $W ^{x,y}$ then it is no longer true that the product of $\cup_{x,y} V ^{x,y}$ and $\cup_{x,y} W ^{x,y}$ is contained in $U$.

Comment: Wow! I didn't note that detail. Then here is where de compactness is needed, not? The collection of all open sets of that form is an open cover for the compact set $A\times B$ and we obtain a finite subcover. Is the finite subcover the open set that we need?

Comment: @CarlosJiménez: No, you need to work with the coordinates one at a time. First show that for each $a\in A$ there is an open nbhd $V_a$ of $a$ and an open $W_a$ in $Y$ such that $\{a\}\times B\subseteq V_a\times W_a\subseteq U$; this uses compactness of $B$. Then use compactness of $A$ in a rather similar fashion to get the desired result.

Comment: The solution: given $a\in A$ fixed then for all $b\in B$ there exist $V(b)$ and $W(b)$ open sets such that $(a,b)\in V(b)\times W(b)\subseteq U$. The collection $\{W(b):b\in B\}$ is an open cover of $B$ and therefore there exist $B_0\subseteq B$ finite such that $B\subseteq \bigcup\{W(b):b\in B_0 \}=W_a$. Define $V_a=\bigcap\{V(b):b\in B_0 \}$. Both are open sets and $\{ a\}\times B\subseteq V_a\times W_a\subseteq U$. We can do this in the same way for all $b\in B$ and the set $A\times \{ b\}$. Finally, we need to consider the union over all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ to conclude. Am I right?

Comment: But a union of sets of the form $U_i \times W_i$ is not good enough since we want a single open set of the type $V \times W$ right?  @CarlosJiménez

Comment: @CarlosJiménez: your comment is a great start! But I would work with the other coordinate in a different way. Once we have $\{a\}\times B\subset V_a\times W_a \subset U$, rather than start fresh, we want to use the fact that these very $V_a$ form an open cover of $A$. Thus there is a finite subcover indexed by an $A_0$, and one can finally take $V=\bigcup \{V_a\colon A\in A_0\}$ and $W=\bigcap \{W_a\colon A\in A_0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

$V^x\times W^y$ subset $U$ does not implies that $V^x\times W^{y'}\subset U$ if $(x,y)\neq (x',y')$.